# Android onCreate() vs Activity Loaded

Tags: android

I am creating an application that checks when the app first loads.  I am creating a value in the `MainActivity` class (before the `onCreate()` method).  I need this because I want something to run only on the first app load.  When is the Activity class loaded?  I know that the `onCreate()` method runs whenever the app opens and renders, but it seems that the Activity is reloading after extended time with the app closed.  Is there a way to store a variable when the app first loads but doesn't reset when `onCreate()` runs?

Comment: Try using shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `Application` and do whatever initialization you are doing inside of the Application's `onCreate()` method. You also need to specify the name of your Application class in your AndroidManifest's `<application>` tag. This will run once every time your app process starts.

If you want to run something the very first time the app is launched and never again (even on future launches), you should still use the Application subclass, but now you also need to store something in SharedPreferences (or elsewhere) that you can check for later to make sure you only do this task once.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor ed=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this).edit();

ed.putString("key","value").commit();
```

And to get back the value from shared preferences do this:

```
String storedValue=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this).getString("key","default Value In Case The Variable Hasn'tBeen Created");
```